# How to create class to extended HTMLElement

Tags: javascript

I have installed module html-element to Node and import it

```
   let HTML = require('html-element');
```

I want to do something like this

```
   class MyElement extends X {
        #xValue = 0;
        constructor() {
        super();
        this.onclick = this.#clicked.bind(this);
        }
           ....
        }
```

I expect that construction

```
  let X =  new HTML.HTMLElement;
```

will working, but no. What correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to change your `MyElement` class;

First, install **html-element** and import it;

```
const HTML = require('html-element');
```

Then you have to extend `HTML.Element`. The updated code will look like this:

```
class MyElement extends HTML.Element {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.#xValue = 0;
        this.onclick = this.#clicked.bind(this);
    }

    #clicked() {
        this.#xValue++;
        console.log('Element clicked', this.#xValue);
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of your custom element

```
const yourNewElement = new MyElement();
```

And at the end, your need to add your custom element to the **DOM**

```
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```